# extjs 4 theming issues in IE9, gridbar color and buttons do not change

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have the following sass code and when I compile it everything works fine in Firefox and chrome.
The only problem I have is in IE where the gridbar color is plain white as compared to the Firefox and Chrome(Blue).
Is there a solution to it. I am using extjs4.
Here is my code for variables

```
    $theme-name: 'slate';


$color1: #abc;
$color2: #3e546b;


$include-missing-images: true;
$base-color: $color1;
$toolbar-background-color:$color1;




//panel
$panel-header-color: #fff;
$panel-header-background-color: $color2;
$panel-border-color: darken($color1, 5);


//grid
$grid-header-color: #fff;
$grid-header-background-color: darken($color1,25);
$grid-header-over-background-color: $color2;
$grid-header-background-gradient: 'glossy';
$grid-header-over-background-gradient: 'glossy';


$grid-row-cell-alt-background: lighten($color1,20);
$grid-row-cell-over-background-color: lighten($color1,10);
$grid-row-cell-over-background-gradient: 'flat';
$grid-row-cell-focus-background-gradient: 'flat';


//window
$window-background-color: $color1;


//buttons
$button-default-color: #fff;
$button-default-base-color: $color2;
$button-default-base-color-over: darken($color1,25);
$button-default-base-color-pressed: darken($color1, 15);
$button-default-background-gradient-over: 'glossy';
$button-default-background-gradient-pressed: 'glossy';


$button-toolbar-border-color-pressed: darken($color1,25);
$button-toolbar-background-color-pressed: darken($color1,25);
$button-toolbar-border-color-over: darken($color1,25);
$button-toolbar-background-color-over: darken($color1, 5);
$button-toolbar-background-gradient: null;
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-over: 'glossy';
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-focus: 'glossy';
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-pressed: 'glossy';
$button-toolbar-background-gradient-disabled: null;
$button-toolbar-color: $color2 !default;
$button-toolbar-color-over: #fff !default;
$button-toolbar-color-pressed: #fff !default;


//tabs
$tab-height: 25px;


$tab-base-color: $color1;
$tab-background-gradient: null;
$tab-base-color-over: darken($color1, 10);
$tab-base-color-active: $color2;
$tab-color-active: #fff;


$tabbar-strip-background-color: $color2;


//progress bar
$progress-bar-background-color: darken($color1,25);


//fieldsets
$fieldset-border-color: $color2;


//datepicker
$datepicker-header-background-color: $color2;
$datepicker-header-background-gradient: 'glossy';
$datepicker-today-item-background-color: $color1;
$datepicker-today-item-border-color: $color2;


$datepicker-th-background-color: $color1;
$datepicker-th-color: $color2;
$datepicker-th-border-bottom-color: $color2;
$datepicker-item-color: #000;
$datepicker-item-hover-background-color: lighten($color1, 15);
$datepicker-selected-item-border-color: $color2;
$datepicker-selected-item-background-color: $color1;
$datepicker-monthpicker-item-color: #fff;


//layout
$accordion-header-color: $color2;
$accordion-header-background-color: $color1;




@import 'ext4/default/all';


// You may remove any of the following modules that you
// do not use in order to create a smaller css file.


@include extjs-boundlist;
@include extjs-button;
@include extjs-btn-group;
@include extjs-datepicker;
@include extjs-colorpicker;
@include extjs-menu;
@include extjs-grid;
@include extjs-form;
    @include extjs-form-field;
    @include extjs-form-fieldset;
    @include extjs-form-file;
    @include extjs-form-checkboxfield;
    @include extjs-form-checkboxgroup;
    @include extjs-form-triggerfield;
    @include extjs-form-htmleditor;
@include extjs-panel;
@include extjs-qtip;
@include extjs-slider;
@include extjs-progress;
@include extjs-toolbar;
@include extjs-window;
@include extjs-messagebox;
@include extjs-tabbar;
@include extjs-tab;
@include extjs-tree;
@include extjs-drawcomponent;
@include extjs-viewport;


// This line changes the location of your images when creating UIs to be relative instead of within the ExtJS directory.
// You MUST set this to true/string value if you are creating new UIs + supporting legacy browsers.
// This only applies to new UIs. It does not apply to default component images (i.e. when changing $base-color)
// The value can either be true, in which case the image path will be "../images/"
// or a string, of where the path is
$relative-image-path-for-uis: true; // defaults to "../images/" when true
```

[image]

[image]

This is how it looks in IE
[image]

Comment: well that whitespace in your images doesn't really help to clarify the problem. anyway, same issue here, will post back when i find a solution

Comment: seems to be some css specificity bug, adding a '!important' to the background declaration did the trick for me (i'm not using ext js' fancy sass theming stuff, so for me it was just: `.x-column-header{background:#717171 !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots posted, it looks like the background images are not sliced for the Grid Header. Please note that the CSS3 gradients are not supported in IE9 [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Please follow the steps below to debug your image slicer.

- Use Sencha cmd to build the application by "sencha app build" command (if you are not already doing it)
- In the console verify you are seeing logs from image slicer including "xxxx images generated"
- If you see an error or "0 images generated", verify if the master image is rendered by phantomjs. This can be done by checking if you have an image named "theme-capture.png" in the `build/<application name>/production` folder. This image should have all your styled components
- If you are not seeing such an image, the phantomjs is not rendering the theme page. View the `/<application name>/sass/example/theme.html` in a browser and make sure it renders all the custom components. It might not sound straight, but the fact is that Sencha CMD is feeding this html file to phantomjs to generate a master image which in turn is sliced by the slicer to generate images to support legacy browsers.